# Python　MeCab　バインディング

Tags: python3, mecab

PythonからMeCabを弄ろうと環境を設定しているのですが、以下のコードの最終行のparse部分で
*UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: invalid continuation byte*
というエラーが発生してしまいます。

```
import MeCab

tagger = MeCab.Tagger('Owakati')
tagger.parse('')

text = '自然言語処理は楽しい'
result = tagger.parse(text)
```

開発環境は、OS：Windows 7 32bit、Python 3.6.0(Anaconda3 4.3.1)、MeCab 0.996
mecab-python　は [ここ](http://qiita.com/yukinoi/items/990b6933d9f21ba0fb43)を参照し、mecab-python-windowsパッケージをpipでインストールしています。
tagger.parse('') はpythonのGCにひっかからないように必要との情報をもとに入れています。

どなたか同様の事象の経験があり、解決された方などいらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Comment: ソースファイルはUTF-8で保存していますよね...?

Answer (score 1):

自己解決いたしました。お騒がせしてしまい申し訳ありません。

Mecab本体のインストール時の文字コード指定をUTF-8以外にしており、後からスタートメニューの「Recompile UTF-8 dictionary」を実行しているのでUTF-8も動作すると考えていました。しかしながら、再インストールを行い、インストール時の文字コード指定をUTF-8にすることで挙動が変化し、正常に動作しました。どうやら、「Recompile xxxx dictionary」は有効ではないようです。

kenji noguchi さんご回答ありがとうございました。